# Can I wall jump up a wall continuously?

Tags: metroid-samus-returns

I just got my copy of the game, and am trying to wall jump up the wall on the right side of the first room, but wall jump seems to launch me too far off the wall to move back towards it for another wall jump. Is this always the case with wall-jumping or do I just need to practice more with the joystick?

If I just need to practice more how do I properly do it?

Comment: You need to list the game

Comment: You need more information or no one can help you, we can't guess what game it is

Comment: @DeathbotGaming Um, the tag shows up for me just fine. It says "metroid-samus-returns". That is the new Metroid game on 3ds which released approximately 15.5 hours ago.

Comment: FWIW, I believe this was possible in both Super and Zero Mission, but not in Fusion.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It was definitely possible in Super Metroid. Zero Mission I think you're right. Fusion you technically CAN single wall jump, but it's freaking ridiculous. See a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC3H1-lLkuw Way beyond my mediocre Metroid skill levels, and probably beyond anyone not doing tool assisted runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't climb a wall using wall jumps. However, in **Area 1** you'll find an item...

> Spider Ball

...that will help you climb any wall you like, as long as it's not slippery.

You also can't wall jump if Samus is sandwiched between walls.

Comment: Yeah, I know about spider ball, and bomb jumping is SUPER easy this time around too. I was wondering for sequence breaking purposes.

Comment: @Fambida, just keep in mind that I'm not a speedrunner, so there *might* exist a glitch that will allow you to wall climb anyway that I'm not aware of. In any case, I didn't manage to wall climb despite trying for about half an hour.

Comment: Sequence breaking is trickier in this game (and Metroid 2) than most Metroid games because of the acid that blocks the paths until you beat a certain number of Metroids.

Comment: For sequence breaking purposes, there's nothing a single-wall wall jump (the subject of this question, which is impossible) could accomplish that infinite bomb jumping doesn't.

Comment: Don't want to spoil too much, but if you use the Power Bomb with the upgrade Nolonar mentioned, you can get around easier as well. I think i may have missed a tooltip, or it just doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The wall jump is similar to the one in Metroid Fusion, where you jump a certain distance away from the wall before regaining control (unlike Super Metroid, where you had immediate control).  As such, you cannot (or it is very hard to) wall jump off the same wall.